# Get first and last position of color

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have created a mask of an image using OpenCV

[image: Mask of image]

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the X and Y positions of the first and last occurrence of a white pixel and store these as variables, please see image below.

[image]

I was thinking I could convert the image to a numpy array and loop through each row comparing the positions against the previous row, but for larger images this could be quick CPU intensive.

Is there a quicker way to get the information?

I can post code to show the above, but the underlying question is if there is a quicker way than scanning and comparing each line.

Comment: A vectorized NumPy approach would be fairly fast. Would that be an option for you?

Comment: @norok2 I am looking into any option for a speed increase at the moment tbh.

Comment: bitwise OR the pixels. For every line find the first position position for white, only continue comparing the next lines up to that position.

Comment: In order to define *"first pixel"* you need to be clearer about where you start looking and which direction you move in. You also need to be clearer about *"white"*, you have many grey pixels in your image, so do you mean [255,255,255] or just *"anything other than coloured or black"*?

Comment: @MarkSetchell sorry for the example image, I created a small images and rescaled it, the array consists of 0's and 255 values.

Comment: If you need a more detailed answer, you should provide a more detailed input / output and potentially go into the details of "first" and "last" pixel definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving this is by using [`scipy.ndimage.find_object()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html).

Assuming your input is consisting only of `1` and `0`, the code reads:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.ndimage


arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
print(arr)
# [[0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 1 0]
#  [0 0 1 0]
#  [0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0]]


slicings = sp.ndimage.find_objects(arr)
print(slicings)
# [(slice(1, 4, None), slice(1, 3, None))]

# : compute corners
# slicings information is: `slicings[label_index][dimension_index]`
top_left_corner = slicings[0][0].start, slicings[0][1].start
bottom_right_corner = slicings[0][0].stop - 1, slicings[0][1].stop - 1
print(top_left_corner)
# (1, 1)
print(bottom_right_corner)
# (3, 2)
```

Actually `find_object()` is more sophisticated and can work for different labels, look into its documentation for more info on how to use it for different scenarios.

If your input is not binary, you could make it binary by using a comparison, e.g. `arr > 0` will produce a boolean array (assuming `arr` is a NumPy array).

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to give a try to a numpy-based implementation.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('blob.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Make sure image is binary (the one you posted was not, probably due to interpolation)
_, image = cv2.threshold(image, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find top left and bottom right coords for non-background pixels
active_pixels = np.stack(np.where(image))
top_left = np.min(active_pixels, axis=1).astype(np.int32)
bottom_right = np.max(active_pixels, axis=1).astype(np.int32)

# Plot them
for keypoint in [top_left, bottom_right]:
    y, x = keypoint
    cv2.drawMarker(image, (x, y), 255, markerType=cv2.MARKER_TILTED_CROSS,
                   markerSize=10, thickness=2)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Beware that this `np.where(image)` creates a potentially large intermediate result, only to get min and max of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the corner points bounding your object in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the image
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold
- Apply morphology open to remove the separate white dots
- Get the contour
- Get the bounding box about the contour
- Use numpy to draw points (in this case 3 pixel blocks for emphasis)
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('odd_shape.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# apply open morphology to remove extraneous white circles
kernel = np.ones((15,15), np.uint8)
thresh_cleaned = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get contours (presumably just one around the nonzero pixels) 
# then get bounding rectangle
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh_cleaned, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    top_left=(x,y)
    bottom_right=(x+w-1,y+h-1)
    print('top left=',top_left)
    print('bottom right=',bottom_right)

# copy image for drawing bounding box
bounding_box = img.copy()

# draw bounding box on image
cv2.rectangle(bounding_box, top_left, bottom_right, (0,0,255), 1)

# copy image for drawing (3px wide) points 
points = img.copy()

# use numpy to draw 3px wide points on image
points[y-1:y+2,x-1:x+2]=[0,0,255]
points[y+h-2:y+h+1,x+w-2:x+w+1]=[0,0,255]

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("thresh_cleaned", thresh_cleaned)
cv2.imshow("bounding_box", bounding_box)
cv2.imshow("points", points)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save image with points drawn
cv2.imwrite('odd_shape_points.png',points)
```

Points (x,y coordinates):

```
top left = (33, 20)
bottom right = (179, 179)
```

Thresholded Image:

[image]

Cleaned Thresolded Image:

[image]

Bounding Box on Image:

[image]

Points drawn on Image:

[image]